# Unclear error: Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

Tags: objective-c

I have the following error:

```
Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
```

The second line gives me the error:

```
    TVConfigurationObject* config = [TVDeviceManger sharedTVDeviceManger].configuration;
    TVInitObj*initObj = config.initObj;
```

in TVDeviceManger.h:

....

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) TVConfigurationObject *configuration;
 + (TVDeviceManger*) sharedTVDeviceManger;
```

....

in TVDeviceManger.m:

....

```
 + (TVDeviceManger*) sharedTVDeviceManger {
    static dispatch_once_t onceQueue;

    dispatch_once(&onceQueue, ^{
       sharedMyManager = [[TVDeviceManger alloc] init];
     });

    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

....

in TVConfigurationObject.h:

....

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) TVInitObj *initObj;
```

....
What's the problem?

Comment: How have you defined the singleton? And split that line up so you can tell which part actually causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ARC, you should retain returned objects for later use.

```
TVConfigurationObject* config = [[TVDeviceManger sharedTVDeviceManger].configuration retain];
```

But, if there's no specific requirement you better use ARC.

Comment: But why? TVConfigurationObject is retained property.

Comment: Looks like you didn't disable ARC for the source file? You will end up changing many places because you should call 'release' matching 'retain'.

Comment: It is retained when you call setter. You are calling getter.

Comment: can you explain this a little more?

Comment: See http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/315502-how-is-this-an-incorrect-decrement-of-reference-count.html#315503.

Comment: A discussion about retained property getter/setter.